# Классификация предложений с помощью gensim(word2vec)

Tags: python, алгоритм, машинное-обучение, семантика, классификация

Как разбить модель word2vec на кластеры методом kmeans(k средних)?  Оптимален ли kmeans для классификации предложений на 10-100, не заданных заранее, классов? Как выбрать оптимальное число кластеров при разбиении с помощью kmeans? Может есть готовые решения для моих задач?

Comment: Так надо ж пробовать. Методов много, заранее сложно сказать, какой лучше взлетит.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам заранее неизвестно число кластеров, то можно попробовать [DBSCAN](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html)

> Perform DBSCAN clustering from vector array or distance matrix.
>
> DBSCAN - Density-Based Spatial Clustering of Applications with Noise.
>   Finds core samples of high density and expands clusters from them.
>   Good for data which contains clusters of similar density.

Очень рекомендую ознакомиться с [документацией по кластерным алгоритмам](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#overview-of-clustering-methods) перед тем как выбрать алгоритм...

Answer (score 2):

Оптимальное число кластеров обычно выбирают с помощью [Elbow Method](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/cluster/elbow.html#:%7E:text=The%20elbow%20method%20runs%20k,point%20to%20its%20assigned%20center.). По этой ссылке есть библиотека, которая может вам красиво нарисовать график для выбора, либо выбрать за вас оптимальное число кластеров.

Но может вам вообще нужен Topic Modeling, а не кластеризация? Не зная задачи сложно сказать. Много всего придумано в области обработки текстов, вы просто можете не знать, какой метод лучше подходит к вашей задаче.